# Intel Edison Johnny five error

Tags: intel-edison, johnny-five

I have been trying to run my hello-worlds.js file on my intel Edison (shown below):

```
var five = require("johnny-five");
var Edison = require("galileo-io");
var board = new five.Board({
io: new Edison()
});


board.on("ready", function() {
 var led = new five.Led(13);
 led.blink(500);
});
```

I have installed Node.js, I also used npm install galileo-io johnny-five and downloaded files to my file directory of folder my-robotics-project.
When i execute using node hello-worlds.js, I get the following error:

```
 This OS image is no longer supported.
 Please upgrade to IoTkit Image with libmraa0 support

 c:\User\Mohamed\my-robotics-project\node_modules\galileo\lib\galileo.js:66
 if <Pin.IO.getPlatformType<> === 2> {

 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPlatformType' of undefined
 at Object.<anonymous> <c:\User\Mohamed\my-robotics-         
 project\node_modules\galileo\lib\galileo.js:66:11>
 at Module._compile <module.js:435:26>
 at Object.Module.extensions..js <module.js:442:10>
 at Module.load <module.js:356:32>
 at function.Module._load <module.js:311:12>
 at Module.require <module.js:366:17>
 at require <module.js:385:17>
 at Object.<anonymous> <c:\User\Mohamed\my-robotics-project\hello-  
 worlds.js:2:14>
 at Module._compile <module.js:435:26>
 at Object.Module._extensions..js <module.js:442:10>
```

Comment: Have you considered upgrading the OS image?

Comment: I have flashed edison board using intel phone lite tool with release 2.1 Yocto. This is the latest image on their site, I still get the same error.

Comment: I also SSHed into edison and used     'echo "src mraa-upm http://iotdk.intel.com/repos/1.1/intelgalactic" > /etc/opkg/mraa-upm.conf
okpg update
opkg upgrade'  mraa upgraded from 0.8.0 to 0.8.1 and upm from 0.4.0 to 0.4.1. I still have the same error

Comment: I tried on my Edison and had no problem.
# node hello.js 
1450662623651 Device(s) Intel Edison  
1450662623667 Connected Intel Edison  
1450662623692 Repl Initialized  
>>

Comment: I can run any sketch using the intel XDK so I know that my edison is working, but nothing works through node.js command prompt. any idea? @tasasaki

Comment: Why not try to prepare and execute everything on Edison (via SSH) without XDK?

Comment: Actually all sketches run on XDK without a problem, I only get the error when running via SSH. I have also update mraa from 0.8.1 to 0.9.0 and i still have same problem (only via SSH) @tasasaki.